# choosing rows by values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) gives a way to choose rows by column value

Here is a DataFrame

```
            0           1
0  877.443401  808.520962
1  826.300620  848.761594
2  824.403359  861.395174
3  866.732033  804.494156
4  853.461260  874.307851
5  822.906499  830.102249
6  852.605652  863.602725
7  893.421600  825.032893
8  863.768363  862.298227
9  899.976622  864.111539
```

with this code `df[df.columns[[1]]]>850`, I got

```
    1
0   False
1   False
2   True
3   False
4   True
5   False
6   True
7   False
8   True
9   True
```

when I run this `df.loc[(df[df.columns[[1]]]>850)]`, I got error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-8a159ef0cec2> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[(df[df.columns[[1]]]>850)]
```

this code `df[df[df.columns[[1]]]>850]` gives

```
    0   1
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN 861.395174
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN 874.307851
5   NaN NaN
6   NaN 863.602725
7   NaN NaN
8   NaN 862.298227
9   NaN 864.111539
```

This is close, what I am trying to get is a new DataFrame consists of rows at [2,4,6,8,9].

How to do that? Thanks to anyone who gives some inspiration.

Comment: Your brackets are wrong. It should be `df[df[1]>850]`

Comment: use single square bracket:  `df[df[1]>850]`.

Comment: you are ending up with a dataframe instead of a series for boolean masking when using multple brackets , as the other comments say , use a single bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df['a']` returns a `pd.Series` while `df[['a']]` returns a `pd.DataFrame` with only column being 'a'. For your problem:

Using `loc`

```py
new_df = df.loc[df[1] > 850].copy()
```

Using `query`

```py
new_df = df.query('a > 850')
```

It's customary using `str` column names instead of `int`. For example, the `query` method would not work with `int` column names and there are a plethora of weird behaviours you can face with `int` column names.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this -

```
df[df[1]>850]
```